# Can the linux kernel enumerate pcie devices beyond what the bios can?

Tags: linux, pci-express

I am trying to build a large system using multiple pcie backplanes. The system bios has a limit on how many devices can be enumerated. Is it possible to force the linux kernel to manage the pcie devices and ignore the configuration space given to it by the bios?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure (well, I don't think it's directly a BIOS limitation, as to my knowledge Linux (as with most modern OSes) doesn't directly call into the BIOS anymore). But are you sure the limitation is not with the hardware? You can't have more devices than the controller has available lanes, unless you have additional switching hardware.

Comment: Perhaps the Linux Kernel Mailing List could answer this question better?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but perhaps useful to other people ending up here with a similar question:

According to the specification, the PCI(e) bus must be enumerated depth first. This means that when a switch or transparent bridge is found, it must be configured and enumeration must continue with devices behind this newly found switch/bridge. After that, it can continue enumeration of devices on the same level the switch/bridge was found. To reduce complexity and memory usage, some BIOSes are limited in the maximum depth it scans. Because you're mentioning multiple backplanes I'm assuming this is the case.

The Linux kernel does not have this limitation. And you can stimulate it to rescan the bus by typing this at your terminal:

`echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer:  no.
The truthful answer: sometimes.
The ugly answer:  once upon a time, yes, but now days, no.
The sad answer:  Intel and AMD CPU/chipset implementations have broken this, and made it impossible for OS to adjust I/O memory maps using standardized P2P bridge locations.  BIOS do a poor job, and cannot deal with hot-plug in most cases, and even when they can, still do a bad job, and the OS can no longer change root port assignments as was intended by the specification.   Intel and AMD do not seem to care.